# Python проверка поля ввода

Tags: python, строки, tkinter

Я делаю программу на Python и пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы если в поле ввода нет символов или только пробелы, то программа отклоняла данные и просила пользователя заполнить ячейки. Я попробовал такой метод, но его можно обойти с помощью большого количества пробелов. Как сделать чтобы программа отклоняла ввод когда введены только пробелы или вообще ничего?

```
    if vvodnazvaniaquizaent.index('end') == 0:
        messagebox.showerror(title='Ошибка', message='Вы не ввели название викторины')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if not vvodnazvaniaquizaent.isalnum():
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо только я вместо vvodnazvaniaquizaent написал quizname